# React: Stop a styled-components animation from running when the component is first mounted

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a `styled-component` that receives props to determine what animation to use. This is controlling an arrow icon that when active rotates 'open' and when inactive remains 'closed'.

Here is what the `styled-component` and two `keyframes` animations look like:

```
const rotate_down = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
`;

const rotate_up = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
`;

const OpenUserSettings = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  animation: ${props => (props.rotate ? rotate_down : rotate_up)} 0.5s ease
    forwards;
  margin-top: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  & > img {
    width: 5px;
  }
`
```

The passed in `rotate` prop is a boolean value that is toggled via an `onClick` handler in the React component:

```
    <OpenUserSettings
      rotate={arrowDown}
      onClick={() => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          arrowDown: !prevState.arrowDown
        }));
      }}
    >
      <img src={OpenArrow} alt="menu drop down arrow" />
    </OpenUserSettings>
```

This works, and when the arrow is clicked, `rotate` prop is passed into `OpenUserSettings` and it successfully toggles between the `rotate_up` and `rotate_down` `keyframes`.

Now my problem is that when the React component first mounts, the `arrowDown` default is set to false meaning that the `rotate` prop is going to be false. This causes the `styled-component` to set the animation to `rotate_up` the first time mounting. I figured this would be hard to visualize so check out this to see what I am describing:

[image]

You can see when the page is refreshed the `rotate_up` animation is firing very quickly. I need the arrow to stay closed, but I do not need the `rotate_up` animation to fire when first loaded to close it. Is this a situation for something like `react-transition-group` where I can control the initial enter or is it something that can be handled with logic?

Answer (score 3):

My first contribution to stack overflow, how exciting!

To assure the animation does not render on mounting, initialise your state with something else as true/false, I remember setting my state to null initially.

In your styled component you can pass null / true / false as a prop and define a function outside your component that performs checks on the null / true / false. (I used TypeScript, so don't copy the types)

```
function showAnimationOrNot(status: boolean | null) {
  if (status === true) {
    return `animation: nameAnimationIn 1s ease forwards;`
  } else if (status === false) {
    return `animation: nameAnimationOut 1s ease-out forwards;`
  } else if (status === null) {
    return ""
  }
}
```

In your styled component simply add a line:

```
${(props: PropsDisplay) => show(props.show)};
```

This is how I did it, I am sure there are more elegant ways, but it did the trick of preforming the animation on mounting.

In return if somebody knows how to get styled component syntax highlighting inside the return of functions like the one I used here (from the example above):

```
return `animation: comeout 1s ease-out forwards;`
```

Do let me know! looking for that! Thank you and good luck!

Keep on animating! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have an easier time with a CSS `transform`/`transition` here, rather than an `animation`. Here's the code:

```
const rotateDeg = props.rotate ? '90deg' : '0deg';

const OpenUserSettings = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: rotate(${rotateDeg});
  margin-top: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  & > img {
    width: 5px;
  }
`
```

I didn't quite understand what position you wanted the arrow in, so you might need to flop `0deg` and `90deg` and I think it might actually be `-90deg`, but hopefully this helps.

**Edit**

Your question was actually how to stop an animation. You can pause a css animation with `animation-play-state`. In this case you could have had the component mount with `animation-play-state: paused;` and then added an additional prop to change that to `running` on first click, but that seems unnecessarily complicated IMO.

[More on `animation-play-state`.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp)